# material ui autoComplete with icons

Tags: reactjs, select, autocomplete, icons, material-ui

Hi I am trying to implement material UI autocomplete dropbox with an icon next to the displayed text.
my implementation is working, but when I select one of the options its not being displayed.
The problem is with this part of the code:

```
renderInput={params => (
                        <Fragment>
                            <TextField
                                {...params}
                                variant="outlined"
                                label="Select Account"
                                placeholder="Favorites"
                                margin="normal"
                                fullWidth
                            />
                        </Fragment>

                    )}
```

if I remove he icon rendering from `getOptionLabel` then when selecting the selected text show just fine.
any help would be very much appreciated.
right now the result of this code looks like:
[image]

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {makeStyles} from "@material-ui/core";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete/Autocomplete";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import FacebookIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Facebook';
import AppleIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Apple';
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";


const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    Select: {
        width: 425,
    },
    icon: {
        color: '#0095e2'
    },
}));

const SelectAccount = ({ clientAccountsData, accountSelected }) => {
    const accountSelectedHandler = async (event, values) => {
        if ( values !== null )
        {
            accountSelected(values);
        }
        else {
            accountSelected('');
        }
    };

    const renderCorrectAccountChannelIcon = (network_id) => {
        if ( network_id=== '1' )
        {
            return (
                <FacebookIcon/>
            );
        }
        else if ( network_id=== '2' )
        {
            return (
                <img
                    src={'/Icons/snapchat.png'}
                    height={30}
                    width={30}
                />
            );
        }
        else if ( network_id=== '3' )
        {
            return (
                <img
                    src={'/Icons/google.png'}
                    height={30}
                    width={30}
                />
            );
        }
        else if ( network_id=== '4' )
        {
            return (
                <AppleIcon/>
            );
        }
    };

    const classes = useStyles();
        return (
            <div className='material-ui'>
                <Autocomplete
                    className={classes.Select}
                    id="account_select"
                    options={clientAccountsData}
                    onChange={accountSelectedHandler}
                    getOptionLabel={option =>
                        {
                            return(
                                <Fragment>
                                    <Icon className={classes.icon}>
                                        {
                                        renderCorrectAccountChannelIcon(option.network_id)
                                        }
                                    </Icon>
                                    {option.accountName + ' (' + option.accountId + ')'}
                                </Fragment>
                            );
                        }
                    }
                    filterSelectedOptions
                    renderInput={params => (
                        <Fragment>
                            <TextField
                                {...params}
                                variant="outlined"
                                label="Select Account"
                                placeholder="Favorites"
                                margin="normal"
                                fullWidth
                            />
                        </Fragment>

                    )}
                />
            </div>
        );
};

SelectAccount.prototypes = {
    accountSelected: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    clientAccountsData: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    clientAccountsData: state.client.clientAccountsData,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(SelectAccount);
```

EDIT!:
Found a fix, we need to use renderOption to render the icon + text
and use getOptionLabel just for the label text
it looks like this:

```
<Autocomplete
                    className={classes.Select}
                    id="account_select"
                    options={clientAccountsData}
                    onChange={accountSelectedHandler}
                    getOptionLabel={option => option.accountName + ' (' + option.accountNumber + ')'}
                    renderOption={option => {
                        return (
                            <Fragment>
                                <Icon className={classes.icon}>
                                    {
                                        renderCorrectAccountChannelIcon(option.network_id)
                                    }
                                </Icon>
                                {option.accountName + ' (' + option.accountNumber + ')'}
                            </Fragment>
                        );
                    }}
                    filterSelectedOptions
                    renderInput={params => (
                        <Fragment>
                            <TextField
                                {...params}
                                variant="outlined"
                                label="Select Account"
                                placeholder="Favorites"
                                margin="normal"
                                fullWidth
                            />
                        </Fragment>

                    )}
                />
```

Comment: Found a fix. 
by material api, to render a specail lable I needed to use renderOption, and for the label getOptionLabel. added code in the main post. check it out.

Answer (score 8):

I want to share maybe a new spin off of this solution that is based of the autocomplete example in the documentation ([autocomplete demos](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/)). Keeps the image in the selected tag as well.

```
<Autocomplete
    multiple
    limitTags={2}
    id="multiple-limit-tags"
    options={top100Films}
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
    defaultValue={[top100Films[13], top100Films[12], top100Films[11]]}
    renderTags={options => 
    {
        return (
            options.map(option =>
                <Fragment>
                    <IconButton color="primary">
                        <img src={'../src/img/Tables.svg'}/> {/*Mock image, attribute in option*/}
                    </IconButton>
                        {option.title}
                </Fragment>))

    }}
    renderOption={option => {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                    <IconButton color="primary">
                        <img src={'../src/img/Tables.svg'}/> {/*Mock image, attribute in option*/}
                    </IconButton>
                {option.title}
            </Fragment>
        );
    }}
    renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField 
            {...params}
            variant="outlined" 
            label="limitTags" 
            placeholder="Favorites" 
        />
    )}
  />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented the above case in the following way using **renderOption** property

```
<Autocomplete
    renderOption={React.useCallback((props, option, { inputValue }) => {
      return (
          <Box component='li' {...props}>
              <div style={{width: '20%'}}/><img src={'../src/img/Tables.svg'}/></div>{option.name}
          </Box>
      )
  })}
/>
```