# How to attach a image at the end of input in react material-ui autocomplete without changing the material-ui design

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I have been trying to change the 'Select' component to the 'Autocomplete' component but couldn't do that since the 'Autocomplete' is not providing an option to attach image at the end of the input. If I try to use the custom render, it's not looking like 'Material-UI' design. Since I am trying to build a form I want the design to be the same as all fields. [I want the autocomplete to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ICn1.png).but I couldn't able to do that. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I believe for your case you could use the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59406081/material-ui-autocomplete-with-icons